# Reading CSV data with yearday column into Pandas as datetime

Tags: python, datetime, csv, pandas

I've got CSV data with yearday as one of the columns instead of usual month and day.  I spent an hour on this and this was the only thing I could get working:  converting all the floating point columns to integer, printing as string and then converting the string to datetime using a custom parse routine:

```
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from StringIO import StringIO

csv = '''Latitude, Longitude, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, YearDay, Year, CruiseID
41.942880, -70.292217, 23, 54, 20, 253, 2011, 11015
41.942865, -70.292160, 23, 54, 22, 253, 2011, 11015
41.942847, -70.292105, 23, 54, 24, 253, 2011, 11015
41.942827, -70.292052, 23, 54, 26, 253, 2011, 11015
41.942803, -70.292002, 23, 54, 28, 253, 2011, 11015

'''

def parse(hr, mn, sec, yearday, yr):
    date_string = '%4.4d %3.3d %2.2d %2.2d %2.2d' % (int(yr), int(yearday), int(hr), int(mn), int(sec))
    return dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y %j %H %M %S")

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv),skipinitialspace=True,
                 parse_dates={'datetime':['Hours','Minutes','Seconds','YearDay','Year']}, 
                 date_parser=parse, index_col='datetime',skipfooter=1)
```

This does indeed give the correct result:

```
print df
                      Latitude  Longitude  CruiseID
datetime                                           
2011-09-10 23:54:20  41.942880 -70.292217     11015
2011-09-10 23:54:22  41.942865 -70.292160     11015
2011-09-10 23:54:24  41.942847 -70.292105     11015
2011-09-10 23:54:26  41.942827 -70.292052     11015
2011-09-10 23:54:28  41.942803 -70.292002     11015
2011-09-11 00:08:48  41.933332 -70.281817     11015
```

But what would be a simpler, better way to read this data?

Comment: That looks like a good way.

Comment: Wow, okay then!  I guess I was bothered by converting to integer and writing out the string.  I could have worked around the integer conversion by assigning dtype in the `read_csv` arguments, I guess, but that's not any simpler.

Comment: Ah yes, couldn't you do a more direct string substitution... Or ' '.join((hour, yearday, ..)). You shouldnt have to convert to int and back!

Comment: Andy, do you want to post the improved solution below so folks can easily find it (and so I can award you the points)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the parse function a little cleaner, without the int convertions:

```
def parse(hr, mn, sec, yearday, yr):
          date_string = ' '.join([yr, yearday, hr, mn, sec])
          return dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y %j %H %M %S")
```

*aside from that, IMO your solution looks good (and I think you do need to write your own parser here).*

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime()` directly.

Example (untested):

```
def parse(hr, mn, sec, yearday, yr):
   date1 = dt.datetime(year=int(yr), month=1, day=1, hour=int(hr), minute=int(mn), second=int(sec))
   return date1 + dt.timedelta(days=yearday-1)
```

Comment: I like this as an alternative to `strptime`.  Seems a little "tricky" though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [strptime '%j'](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) format:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.strptime('253 2011', '%j %Y')
>>> dt.datetime.strptime('253 2011', '%j %Y')
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 10, 0, 0)
```

You can use the comma format directly in strptime as well:

```
>>> dt.datetime.strptime('23, 54, 20, 253, 2011', '%H, %M, %S, %j, %Y')
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 10, 23, 54, 20)
```

Just be aware that that the numbers need to be zero padded. (ie, `01` not `1`)

Comment: I did use the strptime `%j` format in my original example -- maybe I'm missing your suggestion here?